# machine with two WLAN adapter

Tags: networking

I have a ubuntu machine with two  wlan adapters , one (USB) acts as a hotspot , and the second ( PCI ) as normal WiFi adapter . how can I configure the network so that the PCI adapter can connect to the USB hotspot . My goal is each device connects to the hotspot in the same network as the system .I hope I could explain the problem well .sorry for my bad englisch

Comment: So you want to have a single computer connected to the same network with one adapter as AP and one as client?

Comment: yes, I hope that it is feasible

Comment: I'm just wondering why. If you make a hotspot you are already connected to the "hotspot" network. You wouldn't need to connect to it again.

Comment: But if a another device (android smartphone) connected to the hotspot, can I connect the computer and smartphone per ssh?

Comment: What are you using to make the hotspot? I've made a hotspot in the past and I was able to access the hotspot and connected devices via the AP interface.

Comment: thanks @Wilhelm Erasmus it works . I did not think that it's so easy

Comment: No problem. just going to add as an answer so the question can be closed.

Comment: Please mark it as the answer (click the check mark) to close the question when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the community :-)

The hotspot network is already accessible through the AP. Thus, you don't require a second network card.